# String manipulation with vowels not working as intended

Tags: c++, string, c++11

The below program is intended to make all characters in a string lowercase, remove all vowels, and then print a full stop before every letter. For example, an input of "umbrella" would become ".m.b.r.l.l". But when I input "tour", the 'u' is not removed.

```cpp
char ChangeToLow(char letter) {
  if(letter <= 'Z' && letter >= 'A')
    return letter - ('A' - 'a');
  return letter;
}
int main()
{
    string name;
    cin>>name;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < name.length() ; i++)
    {
        name[i] = ChangeToLow(name[i]);
        if (name[i] == 'y' || name[i] == 'a'|| name[i] == 'u'|| name[i] == 'i'|| name[i] == 'e'|| name[i] == 'o')
        {
            name.erase(i,1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < name.length() ; i++)
        {
          cout<<'.'<<name[i];
        }
}
```

I expect the output ".t.r" but instead it prints ".t.u.r".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @jww: It's a common ASCII hack.

Comment: Once you erase a letter all the following letters move left in the string, but you're still incrementing `i`. E.g. if you erase 0, 1 becomes 0 but you then move on to 1 and skip the "new" 0.

Comment: @JonathanPotter This seems like the most likely issue. OP should be able to confirm this behavior by testing any word with two or more vowels next to eachother.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thank you , it worked.

Comment: For this problem you can do it backwards, start at the end of the string `i = name.length()` and end at the start of the string `i >= 0`. This will solve your problems with the array being changed when you erase a char.

Answer (score 4):

When you erase a character from the string, the remaining contents move over to fill the space. Their indexes adjust accordingly. With your tour example, it'll look something like the following:

[image: tour indexes]

Your loop counter, `i`, was incremented to 2 after you deleted the 'o' from tour, and `name[i]` is now 'r'. One option to avoid this behavior is to decrement `i` when you delete a vowel.

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestion for you. Firstly you shouldn't put `using namespace std;` in your code. It just adds confusion and is considered a bad practice. I think it would be also a good thing, if you would consider to learn the STL, if it is really your aim to learn C++ in depths. As for the error I think that the already posted answer shows your wrong assumptions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
        std::string name;
        std::cin>>name;

        std::set<char> vowels={'a','u','i','e','o'};
        std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), [](auto v){ return std::tolower(v, std::locale());});

        auto iter=std::remove_if(name.begin(), name.end(), [&vowels](auto v){ return vowels.find(v)!=vowels.end();});
        name.erase(iter,name.end());

        for (int i = 0 ; i < name.length() ; i++)
        {
                std::cout<<'.'<<name[i];
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Nearly perfect. I would additionally propose to optimize the above further, remove the for loop  and std::copy name to std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, " ")